# How do I send a message to a specific channel without a message object Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying make my bot to send a random question from a `.json` file every two hours into a specific channel. It's not inside any event listener so I don't have a message object to use to send messages.

I've tried defining channel with `client.channels.cache.get('id')` but that just says that `.send` is not defined. Here's my current code:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  const quiz = require('./quiz.json');
  const item = quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
  let channel = client.channels.cache.get('812178275463856128')
  channel.send(item.question)
}, 7200000);
```

Comment: I console.logged the channel variable and it returned undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to [fetch the channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) and check if it's a text channel by accessing the [`type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=type) property:

```js
client.once('ready', async () => {
  console.log('Bot is connected...');

  const quiz = require('./quiz.json');
  const channelID = '812178275463856128';

  try {
    const channel = await client.channels.fetch(channelID);

    if (!channel || channel.type !== 'text')
      return console.log(`Can't send message to this channel`);

    setTimeout(async () => {
      const item = quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];

      channel.send(item.question);
    }, 7200000);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: 05.04 14:02:58 [Bot] HTTPError [DiscordjsError]: Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client.

Comment: Have you logged in? The code above shouldn't throw an error like that. Not sure what the rest of your code looks like...

Comment: Heres my entire login.js: https://pastebin.com/dvXNerWT

Comment: Can you try it with `const channel = await bot.channels.fetch(channelID);` instead?

Comment: I swapped all of the bot functions with client and now there's no error

Comment: And does it find the channel? The problem is I don't know what `bot` and `client` is in your `'./constants'` file

Comment: `export const client = new discord.Client({disableEveryone: true, partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]});
export const bot = new Discord.Client();`

Comment: I removed the setTimeout and re-ran the code and it works fine, thanks for the help!

Comment: excellent  work, this is what saved me